# Source and destination must be different while using Path.Combine()

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a batch charsheet creator for my RPG. When the program loads it looks in its file location `WORKINGDIR + WAITDIR` for any picture files that have the tags `Ready`, `Male` and `Female` tags and puts them in `WORKINGDIR + LIVEDIR`. `WORKINGDIR` looks like this:

```
Debug // WORKINGDIR
├───Live // LIVEDIR
├───Wait // WAITDIR
├───Crew.exe // program
└───Other VS files
```

When the code is run the error `System.IO.IOException: 'Source and destination path must be different.'` is thrown when I try to move the file from one to another. Somehow `source` and `destination` become equivalent.

```cs
const string LIVEDIR = "\\Live";
const string WAITDIR = "\\Wait";
List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(WORKINGDIR + WAITDIR, "*.jpeg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
files.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(WORKINGDIR + WAITDIR, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
files.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(WORKINGDIR + WAITDIR, "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
// ^ adds files that need to be looked through
string[] tags;
ShellFile shellFile;
foreach(string file in files)
{
    string source = Path.Combine(WORKINGDIR, WAITDIR, file);
    string destination = Path.Combine(WORKINGDIR, LIVEDIR, file);
    /*if (source == destination)
        throw new Exception();
    */ // This is also thrown
    shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(Path.Combine(WORKINGDIR, WAITDIR, file));
    tags = shellFile.Properties.System.Photo.TagViewAggregate.Value;
    int i = 0;
    crewMember.Gender foo = crewMember.Gender.Female;
    if (tags == null)
        continue;
    foreach(string tag in tags)
    {
        if(tag == "Ready")
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(tag == "Female")
        {
            i++;
            foo = crewMember.Gender.Female;
        }
        else if(tag == "Male")
        {
            i++;
            foo = crewMember.Gender.Male;
        }
    }

    if(i>=2) // if it has two correct tags
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"source:      {source}\n" +
            $"Destination: {destination}");
        // ^ also writes the same paths to console.
        Directory.Move(source, destination);
        // ^ Error
        crewMembers.Add(new crewMember(file, foo));
    }
}
```

What I think is going on is that for whatever reason `Path.Combine()` is returning the string that was generated previous instead of a new string. Is there a way around this or am I using it wrong?

Comment: Are the strings in `files` absolute paths?

Comment: Breakpoint the code and inspect variables.. Would be much easier than us guessing

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] on a fiddler (e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @JanWichelmann The first param `WORKINGDIR` is absolute because it is the path that the program is in. It starts with `C:\\Users\\user\\...`. On closer inspection I see that `file` is absolute. So I need to add `Path.GetFileName()` around `file` to make the new path. Also for whatever reason I don't have `Join` or `TryJoin` methods.

Comment: @DoshorteDovencio Yes, exactly. I have updated my answer: `Path.Join` is not available for .NET Framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `Directory.EnumerateFiles` gives [absolute paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles), so each of your `file` variables contains an absolute path.

If you supply multiple absolute paths to `Path.Combine`, it will output the last one:

```cs
Path.Combine("C:\\", "workdir", "C:\\outdir\\test.txt")
```

yields

```
C:\outdir\test.txt
```

([Try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fF0Txr)).

This is, because the `Path.Combine` method tries to [root the output path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8):

> However, if an argument other than the first contains a rooted path, any previous path components are ignored, and the returned string begins with that rooted path component.

Especially for applications which take file names as user input this is **a common security pitfall**.

Instead either use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8) to get plain file names first, or, if you have access to .NET Core, combine the paths using the new and more secure [`Path.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.join?view=netcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8) method.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [PhysicalFileProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.physicalfileprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) for enumeration, which returns `IFileInfo` instances on which you can query the `Name` directly.

This approach makes it more testable.